# Automatically display function documentation in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I would like to automatically display function documentation in vim, in a small window like in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yV0Q.png. I have coc but I don't know how to configure it to make it possible. I have Neo Vim in MacOS.

Comment: Read the docs [here](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/a9b682ad79cc4b7b836fc7e31f7d01ecd88d7c51/doc/coc.txt) and [here](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki) for the plugin you installed. You probably want to look for the word "signature". Reading all of it is a good idea if you don't know how to use it. Before installing it, preferably.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. In case of react and javascript, I runned CocInstall coc-tsserver [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Itm.jpg)